# Studying the integrability of a function $f:\mathbb R^3\to\mathbb R$ in a neighbourhood of its singularity

Tags: measure-theory, lebesgue-integral, lebesgue-measure, measurable-functions

Today we solved for the first time exercises concerning the Lebesgue integrabilty of functions in $2$ or $3$ variables.
We followed a standard method for every exercise. For example, consider a function $f:\mathbb R^3\to\mathbb R$ with a singularity in the origin and suppose we want to study the integrability on a region $E\subset\mathbb R^3$ s.t. $(0,0,0)\in\mathbb R^3$.
We know that $f\in\mathcal C^0(\mathbb R^3\setminus\{(0,0,0)\})$ so, in order to discuss the convergence of $\iiint _E f(x,y,z)dxdydz$, we considered a set like $\mathbb B_{\varepsilon}(\textbf 0)$,  $[-\varepsilon,\varepsilon]^3$ or $[0,\varepsilon]^3$ and we studied (for example)
$$\lim_{\varepsilon\to 0}\iiint_{E\setminus \mathbb B_{\varepsilon}(\textbf 0)}f(x,y,z)dxdydz.$$
So I wondered why we did this, I wanted to undertand the reason behind this process. If the functionn is integrable, then the integral of $f$ does not depend to which sets we remove but I don't think we saw a similar result in theory lessons.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To simplify I will take $E = \overline{\mathcal{B}}(0,r)$, you know that $f$ is continuous on $E \setminus \{0\}$ so for each $0 < \epsilon < r$ the integral
$$ \int_{E \setminus \mathcal{B}(0,\epsilon)} f d \lambda $$
is the integral of a continuous function on a compact set. It is therefore well defined as a real number. Now you are interested in weather or not the integral
$$ \int_E |f| d\lambda$$
is finite. The link between these two integrals is that
$$|f| 1_{E \setminus \mathcal{B}(0,\epsilon)} \rightarrow |f|$$
when $\epsilon$ goes to 0, for almost every $x \in E$. This convergence is increasing so by the Beppo-Levi's lemma you have that
$$ \int_E |f| d\lambda = \lim_{\epsilon \rightarrow 0}  \int_{E \setminus \mathcal{B}(0,\epsilon)} |f| d \lambda.$$
Now you have to bound from above the right hand term with something finite that doesn't depend on $\epsilon$.

If you assume $f$ to be integrable on all $\mathbb{R}³$ then you have automatically $f$ integrable on $E$ and there is no need to introduce those integrals. But in general a function that is merely continuous is not integrable.

Does this answer your question ?

Comment: This is really helpful but my question is more focused on "why" we need to remove the set. What's the advantange we get with this operation? Which problems we bypass?

Comment: Wide question so I will try to give you a wide answer.

Comment: First, this method gives a general way to check a convergence. You may note that without more information your problem is not solvable so the solution has to come from more information on $f$'s behavior.

Comment: Second, it is convenient to restrain ourself to domination. Domination is very natural in analysis and easy to practice : start brutal, check if it works, if not try to thighten your bounds and so on.

Comment: Third, this operation of approaching the integration set by an increasing limit of more regular set is classic in integration. It is convenient because it allows to connect the computations done on regular set with the integrability on a more general one.

Comment: I accepted tour answer:-). What do you mean with "without more information your problem is not solvable"

Comment: For example I know that the function is continuos without singularities in every point of the domain of integration which does not contain a neighbourhood of the origin. So in these points I can use Tonelli's theorem and I can check the result I obtain with the limit with the integral on the whole domain of $f$. Does this nave dense?

Comment: Your integration domain is any borelian set $E$ that contains $0$ and $f$ is any function continuous on $E \setminus \{ 0 \}$. For instance take $E = \mathcal{B}(0,1)$ and $f(x) = 1/|x|^{\alpha}$, for which $\alpha$ does $f$ is integrable? Some will make it and some won't.

Answer (score 1):

Because of the following theorem:

> Let $ A_1 \subseteq A_2 \subseteq \cdots $ be an increasing sequence
> of measurable sets with union $ A = \bigcup_{n=1}^\infty A_n $. If
> $$ \lim_{n \to \infty} \int_{A_n} |f(x)| dx < \infty $$ then $f$ is
> integrable on $A$ and we have $$ \int_A f(x) dx = \lim_{n \to \infty}
>  \int_{A_n} f(x) dx $$

This can be proved by the dominated convergence theorem and I leave it as an exercise.

Now, let $ A_n = E\setminus \mathbb B_\frac{1}{n}(0) $ for each $n \in \mathbb{N}$. Then $ \{A_n\} $ is an increasing sequence of measurable sets with union $ E \setminus \{0\} $. Moreover, we have

$$
\lim_{\epsilon \to 0} \int_{E\setminus \mathbb B_{\epsilon}(0)} |f(x)| dx
= \lim_{n \to \infty} \int_{A_n} |f(x)| dx
$$

If the above quantity is finite, then by the theorem stated in the beginning, $f$ is integrable on $E$ and satisfies

$$
\lim_{\epsilon \to 0} \int_{E\setminus \mathbb B_{\epsilon}(0)} f(x) dx
= \lim_{n \to \infty} \int_{A_n} f(x) dx
= \int_{E} f(x) dx
$$

because $E$ has the same measure as $ E \setminus \{0\} $.

Comment: By choosing $f_n(x):=f(x)\chi_{A_n}$ I suppose (?) But why it is convenient to remove this sets from the domain of integration?